# Avoid adding zsh command to history

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

I use the following binding to allow me to press Control-Z to resume a program I previously backgrounded. I set `histoptignorespace` and put a space in front of `fg` so the command doesn't persist in my history.

However, it still appears when I press the up arrow. Any way to remove this as well? I would like pressing the up arrow to ignore the fact that `fg` was ever entered.

```
# Allow Ctrl-z to toggle between suspend and resume                             
function Resume {                                                               
  zle push-input                                                                   
  BUFFER=" fg"                                                                     
  zle accept-line                                                                  
}                                                                                  
zle -N Resume                                                                                                                                                  
bindkey "^Z" Resume
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, alas. The "up history" is really just replaying what you typed.

Comment: @ChrisKitching I think you're basically right although it turns out that running `fg` directly followed by accepting an empty line solves my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me. It really just runs `fg` directly. The rest is necessary to get back to the prompt.

```
# Allow Ctrl-z to toggle between suspend and resume
function Resume {
  fg
  zle push-input
  BUFFER=""
  zle accept-line
}
zle -N Resume
bindkey "^Z" Resume
```